# Send mail when Outlook is not already open

Tags: vba, outlook

**My situation:**

I'm trying to send e-mails while Outlook is not open. This code will work if Outlook is running. If Outlook is closed the code will create a non-visible process that you can see running in Task Manager.

The code encounters an error during the `.Send`. It returns runtime error 287.

From my experience that are certain VBA methods that will only work when the object is either visible or active.

My work around is to use `.Display(False)` before calling `.Send`.

After calling `.Send` it immediately terminates the Outlook process. (Please point me to the right direction why.) Then the e-mail gets stuck in the Outbox.

I have to apply another work around by calling another `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and either looping through the Outbox `While Outbox.Items.Count > 0`

or

Looping through `SyncObjects` and manually calling `.Start` to run Send/Receive on the Outbox.

**My question:**

Is there a way to directly use the `.Send` method instead of using work arounds while also not having to open Outlook.

**My code:**

```
Sub emailer()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .to = "f@r.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .Body = "Hi there"
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: try putting the "While Outbox.Items.Count > 0" loop into your code right after the "End With" line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Namespace.SendAndReceive`. Keep in mind that Send/Receive is asynchronous and you need to wait to the sync to finish. You can use `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection, start a sync using `SyncObject.Start`, then wait for the `SyncObject.SyncEnd` event.

To prevent Outlook from closing, you need to keep a live reference to an Outlook Explorer or Inspector object. You can retrieve the Inbox folder using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, then use `MAPIFolder.GetExplorer` method to get a pointer to an Explorer object.

**UPDATE**:

You might also want to make sure that you log to a MAPI profile before you create and send a message. After the CreateObject line, try to add the following

```
set NS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
NS.Logon
```

Comment: Do you know why `.Send` does not want to work when there is no explorer object?

Comment: Because Outlook exits before it has a chance to perform Send/Receive.

Comment: I don't think thats the reason. When trying to execute .Send I can still see Outlook.exe in Resource Monitor runnning

Comment: When does it exit? Does it receive emails? Do you see new mail notification when it is in that hidden state?

Comment: Strictly following the code in my original question. With Outlook not open. It will raise a runtime error 287 when trying to execute .Send. So it does not exit. And yea I recieve notification even in hidden state. If I leave the code at .Body line, it will recieve mails and notifications.

Comment: After the CreateObject line, try to add the following: set NS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")    NS.Logon

Comment: Hey I just tried this and it works in VBA. I will have to try it in python. Thanks! If you edit your answer to add the latest suggestion then I will select it as the correct answer. So people will be able to find the answer easier instead of looking in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for the .send issue with Outlook closing can possibly be resolved by changing the settings for Send/Receive.  Go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> find `Send/Receive...` and press it.  Under "Setting for group "All Accounts" is a checkbox for `Perform an automatic send/receive when exiting`. Check this, and it may resolve the "stuck in the outbox issue you are having".

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Give this a try, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hi @Busse thanks but it only gets stuck if I use the `.Display` and `.Send` combo.

I want a straightforward `.Send`. If I only use `.Send`, I get a Run-time Error 287

Comment: Ah, sorry. How are you calling this script?  Outlook is closed, you call this script, it creates a new mail item, and attempts to send.  Since it's opening the process it should send.  I read somewhere that it may be a timing thing, indicating that it is trying to send too quickly, so they added a 1 second delay before sending.

Comment: I'm using VBA in Excel but my program is really in Python. I'm using `pywin32` library which exposes COM objects. So it's like running VBA code in Python. I just created a duplicate code in VBA to make sure it's not an issue with Python.

I tried using F8 to run through the code and pausing a long time before executing the `.Send` line but it still doesn't work.

I think the issue is I can't use `.Send` when Outlook is not visible. Similar to `.Paste` in Excel. Where you can't use it if the destination field is not activated.